# Double click listview item and pass the variable to another page to run a search

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview

I have 2 forms; MainWindow and OwnerShares. There is a search on MainWindow that looks up what items are being shared. OwnerShares has a search function that looks up the owner details and what they are sharing. On OwnerShares the options are displayed in a ListView. What i want to do is allow the user to double click on a row in ListView and be directed to the MainWindow which runs the SEARCH based on the value that was selected from the ListView. The variable ACEName will be the one that i want to pass to the MainWindow form search.

```
Private Sub listSearchOwner_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles listSearchOwner.MouseDoubleClick
    Dim ACEName As String
    ACEName = listSearchOwner.SelectedItems(0).xShareName
    OwnerShares.Close()
End Sub
```

The name of the search in MainWindow is (cmdSearch_Click). I am currently getting the value that i click on with the above code. I just dont know how to open the MainWindow form and run the search command automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly you could just call show your form and run your other routine

```
Private Sub listSearchOwner_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles listSearchOwner.MouseDoubleClick
Dim ACEName As String
ACEName = listSearchOwner.SelectedItems(0).xShareName
OwnerShares.Close()

MainWindow.show()
' YourMethod or Button here. 


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach it this way:

1. Add a `module` to your project, if you don't have one.
2. Create a `public` variable in the `module`, e.g.

   Public VariableName As DataType
3. Everytime that you `double-click` the `listview` control, assign a value to your variable.
4. After getting the value stored in the public variable, delete the value to create a room to pass another value again.

That should do the trick.